# grails 2.1.2 log4j configuration strange behavior

Tags: grails, logging, configuration, log4j

I have following log4j configuration:

```
log4j = {   
    appenders {
        appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(name: 'dailyAppender', ...)
    }

    root {
        error 'dailyAppender'
    }

    info 'dailyAppender' : 'com.intelli', 'grails.app'
}
```

the "grails.app" logger is for grails artefacts (service, controllers, ..), while the "com.intelli" is for other custom loggers (like /src/groovy/**, ...) initialized with LogFactory class.

Now the issue is, that with this configuration **the custom loggers ('com.intelli') were not logging anything**. However grails controllers and services were logging fine!

When I changed the order of loggers:

```
log4j = {   
    ...

    info 'dailyAppender' : 'grails.app', 'com.intelli'
}
```

The custom loggers were logging fine, however **grails services and controllers  were not logging at all**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very tricky, you need to enclose the loggers in list ("[ ]") brackets:

```
log4j = {   
    appenders {
        appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(name: 'dailyAppender', ...)
    }

    root {
        error 'dailyAppender', additivity: false
    }

    info 'dailyAppender' : ['com.intelli', 'grails.app']
}
```

With this config, everything logs as it should.

This is not part of the issue, but to prevent double logging, we need to set additivity to false:

```
log4j = {   
    appenders {
        appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(name: 'dailyAppender', ...)
    }

    root {
        error 'dailyAppender'
    }

    info 'dailyAppender' : ['com.intelli', 'grails.app'], additivity: false
}
```